# How can I drag selected text from iframe to input/textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, drag-and-drop, draggable

Consider this simple example:

```html
<input type="text">
<br />
<p>test text</p>
<br />
<iframe src="//wikipedia.org/">
```

I can drag selected text to input from page, but not from iframe:

[image]

---

Question is - how can I make it work? (js, css, browser extension, etc.)

I don't have access to inner content of iframe.

Comment: if you use chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=251718

Answer (score 0):

Mouse events over `iframe` aren't fired in the parent document so there's nothing to relay. The usual workaround is to add a transparent `div` over the `iframe` so that the `div` will receive the events.